# Averaging a count group

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DATE( DATE ) DATE, COUNT( number ) totalCOunt
FROM numbers
GROUP BY DATE( DATE ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30

   DATE    totalCOunt
2013-01-01 13
2013-01-02 12
2013-01-03 22
2013-01-04 14
2013-01-05 14
2013-01-06 16
2013-01-07 13
2013-01-08 22
etc
```

How can I get average of this data? I failed many attempts of doing it, I can ether do it in the sql or foreach php function, but it seems like sql query will be faster executed?

Comment: `DATE( DATE ) DATE` consider using a different column name and alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sub-select:

```
SELECT AVG(totalCount) FROM (
    SELECT DATE( DATE ) DATE, COUNT( number ) totalCOunt
    FROM numbers
    GROUP BY DATE( DATE ) 
    LIMIT 0 , 30) TBL1
```

Comment: Error : Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @user3793639 I added the alias.

Comment: Hm seems reasonable, this means I need to run this query along my main query? Or can I get the results in 1 query ( is this even effective )?

Comment: @user3793639 this is one query. If you need both the average and the actual data, either calculate the average in code, or use two queries.

Comment: Thats what I thought which is more effective with large data?

Comment: @user3793639 I guess you mean efficient, not effective. I'd say what large data sets, doing it in code is more efficient, as you are processing all rows anyway. That being said, you can only be sure after benchmarking.